# Как заменить символ в указателе на строку char*?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, преобразование-типов

Хочу сделать изменение любого выбранного символа в массиве через указатели.

```
char *str = "Hello";
*static_cast<char*>( (str + sizeof(char) * 1) ) = 'K';
```

Но ничего не выходит, как можно такое реализовать? и вообще можно ли?
Суть в том чтобы указать на нужный символ, найти его адрес в памяти и по этому адресу заменить значение.

Comment: (1) `str[1] = 'a';`, но вы пытаетесь изменить литерал, так делать просто нельзя, в C++ нету встроенной защиты от дурака и вы должны следить за соблюдением правил сами; (2) А какой компилятор это вам скомпилировал?

Comment: @VladD - GCC, кстати ваш пример не работает. `char *str = "Hello";
    str[1] = 'G';
    cout << str << endl;` ничего не выдает. Тот же результат что и в моем примере.

Comment: @VladD А можно ли как-то вообще его так изменить? без лишних телодвижений как проходом циклом выделением новой памяти и т.д. ?

Comment: Потому что так делать (изменять литерал) нельзя. Попробуйте так: `char str[] = "Hello";     str[1] = 'G';     cout << str << endl;`

Comment: GCC скомпилировал без warning'а?

Comment: @VladD Да, никаких предупреждений, совсем ничего.

Comment: Странно, я был о GCC лучшего мнения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++ (в отличии от C) строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Поэтому правильно будет написать

```
const char *str = "Hello";
```

И в C++, и в C любая попытка изменить строковый литерал ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Вы могли бы определить символьный массив, инициализировав его строковым литералом. Например,

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

Тогда бы вы могли написать просто

```
*( str + 1 ) = 'K';
```

Не имеет смысла использовать приведение типов `static_cast<char *>`, так как выражение `str + sizeof(char) * 1` уже имеет тип `char *` и эквивалентно выражению `str + 1`.

Выражение  `sizeof(char)` всегда равно 1.

Comment: Странно, что gcc не выдал ошибку или хотя бы предупреждение.

Comment: @VladD Возможно это связано с установленными опциями по умолчанию для компилятора. Кроме того для обеспечения совместимости со старым кодом, компилятор может пропускать такое объявление указателя.